# Stream a batch process into a CSV java 7

Tags: java, list, download, stream, inputstream

Currently I want to steam the result of a series of calls to an external server into a csv download.

```
List<List<String>> masterList;
for(int i = 0 ; i<numberOfPages ; i++){
    List<List<String>> subList = parseResponse(callServer(int from, int number));
    masterList.addAll(sublist);
}
Filedownload.save(generateCVS(masterList).getBytes());
```

This is currently working fine, however, when the number of pages is high the file download does not begins until the full object is in memory.

I want to now if its posible and how to generate the byte stream on the fly so the download can start while the masterlist is being generated

thank you

Edit:

callServer does a call to a rest service
parseResponse, parses the service responce into a List>
generateCSV parses the list into a CSV formated String
Filedownload is from Zul Api

Comment: can you include what `parseResponse`,  `callServer`, `Filedownload.save`, and `generateCVS`, do

Comment: The question here is whether the Filedownload instance is able to provide you an OutputStream which you can open, feed the content chunk by chunk and finally flush/close if all content is delivered. It also depends if you can do all the desired transformations (parse, generateCSV) 'on the fly' without the need to wait until the end of the incoming content(s). If you can confirm this two questions you probably want to do the two operations in two separate threads.

Answer (score 1):

Your `List<List<String>> subList = parseResponse(callServer(int from, int number));` block the subsequent statements so you have to wait.

If you want to stream your response bytes to your local files, you have to access the `InputStream` from HttpServletResponse. And process your bytes as you read from response

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was thinking of a custom implementation of an InputStream, which implementation of read could be the for loop, however, i have no idea if this could work

Comment: If one page data size is not big, you can start write response to bytes everytime you got response from `parseResponse(callServer(int from, int number))`. No need to wait the full for loop.